# Trying to multiply each number in a list using a list comprehension but not working

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

When I run the code, I just get list2 all over again.

```
list1 = [range(100,201)]
print list1 

list2 = [list1*5]
print list2 

list3 = list2  
list3 = [i * 5 for i in list3] 
print list3
```

I've tried using this code as recommended on another thread but it still does not work.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_new_list = [i * 5 for i in my_list]

print(my_new_list)
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Comment: It seems that the code you were given works. In yours, you create a new list 5 times bigger than the one before. Why?

Comment: It looks like it works. What is your expected output with `my_new_list = [i * 5 for i in my_list]` ?

Comment: In your first code when you multiply `list1*5` you are concatenating `list1` 5 times. The correct way to do it is the code you showed next, which is indeed working properly. What did you expect?

Comment: @Matthieu it's for an assignment for school. I have experience with Java but not python

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool for the task: arrays instead of lists. Not only is it more convenient but also substantially faster.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list1 = np.arange(100, 201)
>>> list1
array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112,
       113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125,
       126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138,
       139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151,
       152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164,
       165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177,
       178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190,
       191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200])
>>> list2 = 5 * list1
>>> list2
array([ 500,  505,  510,  515,  520,  525,  530,  535,  540,  545,  550,
        555,  560,  565,  570,  575,  580,  585,  590,  595,  600,  605,
        610,  615,  620,  625,  630,  635,  640,  645,  650,  655,  660,
        665,  670,  675,  680,  685,  690,  695,  700,  705,  710,  715,
        720,  725,  730,  735,  740,  745,  750,  755,  760,  765,  770,
        775,  780,  785,  790,  795,  800,  805,  810,  815,  820,  825,
        830,  835,  840,  845,  850,  855,  860,  865,  870,  875,  880,
        885,  890,  895,  900,  905,  910,  915,  920,  925,  930,  935,
        940,  945,  950,  955,  960,  965,  970,  975,  980,  985,  990,
        995, 1000])
```